# C global function (not C++)

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, global

I'm trying to have a global function in C. Something that can be called from different files.

I know how to make a global variable by declaring it (with extern) in all files except one, and defining it in just one file (without the extern).

I need a - possibly simple - solution that can work with C89 (I'm using VS2013).

I'm compiling in C mode right now, but I'd like this to work if I switch to C++ mode later.

Thanks.

Comment: extern will work with functions as well in the same way. But better use header files to include...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaration, usually in a *.h* file but also possible to just copy-paste to a *.c* file directly (for quick & dirty testing etc, for any real code you should write a proper *.h* file). Duplicates in same compilation unit are are ok as long as they match. You can use `extern` like with variables, but it's not necessary, compiler will know this is just function declaration because there is no function body, `{}`. Also since there is not `static` keyword, compiler assumes this is a global symbol.

```
int my_global_function(const char *string);
```

---

Definition, in exactly one *.c* file (more formally a compilation unit), so it will be in exactly one *.o* file (or library), otherwise linker will complain.:

```
int my_global_function(const char *string)
{
    puts(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But it is better to have a single prototype declaration in the same header file that is included in the C file that implements the function: then the compiler will check if the prototype matches its implementation.

Comment: I used headers with function declarations AND extern in front of all declarations except one. It works. Is it good or bad practice?

Comment: @Agostino I would not use `extern` with function declarations in `.h` files, but if you do, be consistent and use I same way, with same logic, everywhere. AFAIK it makes no difference to the C compiler.